# Филлинг или филинг?

Tags: заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

Филлинг или филинг (метод избавления от морщин)?

Answer (score 1):

Filling, следовательно филлинг. Скорее всего двойные согласные сохраняются.

Answer (score 1):

Графика слова неустоявшаяся, применяются оба варианта.

Вот эстетическая медицина в Израиле предлагает устранение морщин методом филинга. Это инъекционный метод пластики лица, связанный с введением под кожу специальных веществ - филлеров, заполняющих собой дефекты (от англ fill - наполнять). В данном случае использована запись с одной буквой Л, то есть графика оригинала не сохраняется.

В словарях слово еще отсутствует, а вариант с двумя ЛЛ в текстах также встречается, тем более что существует англ. слово feel - чувствовать и термин feeling scin - чувствительная кожа. Казалось бы, надо как-то различать эти понятия и сохранить две ЛЛ в названии "филлинг", да и слово "филлер" пишется с двумя ЛЛ.

Создается впечатление, что для заимствованных слов стремятся применить экономную графику без удвоения согласных. К примеру, запись "блогер" очень долго вызывала дискуссии, но там было применено правило: если слово "блог" существует в языке, то словообразование должно происходить на русской почве - с помощью суффикса ЕР без удвоения согласных (а вариант блоггер - это полностью заимствованное слово).